# Dettaching Nunit from VS debug mode takes too long

Tags: visual-studio-2008, nunit, loading, spring.net

I am using VS2008 and Nunit. My application uses Spring.NET Framework for dependency injection. I attached Nunit to VS to debug. Loading Nunit takes time and even worse after the test fails/success, I stop it. deattaching duration is more than 2 minutes. 
I tried to restart everything, clear the cache on "\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files", but did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: it happens to be at only one solution, not any others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Reshaper keeping me hold. With removing as add-in did solve the issue.